# Got "sort: /dev/fd/63: end of file" when sorting files

Tags: bash, pipe

I have searched online and use the following bash script (test.sh) to sort files from the directory with assigned random seeds:

```
#!/bin/bash
get_seeded_random()
{
  seed="$1"
  openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$seed" -nosalt \
    </dev/zero 2>/dev/null
}

ls |sort -R --random-source=<(get_seeded_random $1)
```

When I run:

```
./test.sh 405
```

I got:

```
sort: /dev/fd/63: end of file
```

The bash --version i am using is 
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Could some one help me here? it seems to work fine for me in another container where the bash --version is GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, your function is looking for a seed that you are supposed to pass as an argument to your test.sh script ($1)

```
./test.sh <seed>
```

When your script is doing `<(get_seeded_random $1)`, the file descriptor `/dev/fd/63` is used to provide the output of your `get_seeded_random()` function to `sort`. Because the function does not have this seed, `dev/fd/63` is empty.

Comment: Hi gui.co, I forgot to put the seed in the question. Actually I did use a seed, like ./test.sh 405 and I got the same error. And the same script works in another environment with bash version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: From what you said in your two comments, it seems that `openssl` is not installed on your machine. That is why you get this `/dev/fd/63: end of file` error. Try to install it and redo either your command or oliv's.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 problems with your script.

- Giving `/dev/zero` as input file for `openssl` is not a good idea since it has an infinite length
- `$seed` is empty which result in the `openssl` password to be blank

You could solve both problem by something like

```
sort -R --random-source=<(dd if=/dev/zero count=1 | openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$seed" -nosalt)
```

and make you call your script with `./test "mysecretpassword"`

**But please don't!** It's a very ugly way to get random folder entries.

If your only goal is to have the file of your folder in a random order, please use `shuf` command:

```
shuf -e *
```

Comment: Hi oliv, I want a random sort but keep the seed fixed so that the result does not change. I have modified this in the original question. Also, I tried your code, got the following error                                          
openssl: command not found
sort: /dev/fd/63: end of file

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [Shuffle output of find with fixed seed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60266215/1506477)

The `--random-source` needs to have more bytes than `42` or such small string.

---

Suggestion: point --random-source to the input file itself, so same input is shuffled same way, if you care for reproducing the experiments (as in my case)